# formatLocalized, format minutes

Tags: laravel, time, php-carbon

I'm reading an Excel file with:

```
$data = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($archivo_procesar, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
```

Then Im trying to get the time (hours:minutes:00) from my "time" with

```
$time = $data["time"]->formatLocalized('%H:%m:00');
```

When I do `dd($time);` I get `"05:11:00"`. 05 is ok for the hours, 00 is ok because I need always 00 as seconds, but 11 is not the minutes is the month of that date, but I need to read the minutes. I tried with `'%H:%i:00'` or `'%H:%mm:00'` but I'm getting errores. How should I used the formatLocalized for to get the minutes ok?

Comment: Is your `$data["time"]` a Carbon instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in Carbon `formatLocalized` method :

`$formatted = strftime($format, strtotime($this->toDateTimeString()));`

It uses [`strftime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and as we can see in the documentation, the two digit representation of the minute is `%M`.

So you should use `$time = $data["time"]->formatLocalized('%H:%M:00');`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found too. Thanks.